# Kendoui Chart - how to know the chart has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui chart.  It gets a lot of data from the server.

I found out how to find when the data has loaded.

The problem is that when there is a lot of data, the graph can take 2 to 5 seconds just to plot.  Is there a way to know the time the graph is ready?

Comment: I don't see anything in the API documentation to know when a chart has finished drawing. [API Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart)

Comment: Me too - this is why I'm asking here :)

Answer (score 4):

There is now a hookup for the render event.  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/events

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
   ...
   render: onRender,
   ...
});

function onRender(e) {
    console.log("Render");
}
```

Comment: It's works, I was using dataBound, but the render override my text, now whenb using render my texts show ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dataBound` inside kendoChart object:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataBound: function () {
        console.log("loading is done");
    }
    // other code
    // ...
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siliconsoul/hjLhe/13/) (not my work, I believe it's courtesy of Daniel, admin @ Telerik forums).

Comment: Thanks, but I have already found this solution ("I found out how to find when the data has loaded."), but it only tells when the data is bound - not if the data has loaded.

Comment: @yccteam The data being bound and loaded mean the same thing in this context. What you mean to ask is when the data has finished rendering. Unfortunately, there is no hook for this event.

Comment: Thanks @Brett, I was looking if there is maybe any reference in the docs. I don't know why you would need this event. If you know when the data is loaded, the render time should be constant, so if you wait lets say .5 or 1 second and then continue with code that should be executed after loading/rendering the data.

Comment: Thank you all. @maremp, when handling with big data sets, there's a huge lag between data binding and the data rendering, for some reason.

Comment: @maremp Render time is not constant.  With a scatter plot for example, you can see it adding points one by one.